# Two full screen videos background side by side in one window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, video

I have two videos that are side by side in the browser, and I want them to have the full size of the browser window. I don't care about cropping the videos. I would like to have them centered in the middle of the video each on both sides with the overflow on the top, bottom, right, and left hidden. I want to achieve this effect (http://css-tricks.com/multiple-backgrounds-left-half-and-right-half/), but with videos essentially.

my code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

<style>
#leftHalf {
   width: 50%;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0px;
   overflow: hidden;
}
#rightHalf {
   width: 50%;
   position: absolute;
   right: 0px;
   overflow: hidden;
}
</style>

</head>


<body>

<!--This is the code that's not working, should have specified-->
    <video id="rightHalf"width="100%" height="100%" preload autoplay loop muted>
          <source src="videos/sky.webmsd.webm" type="video/webm">
          <source src="videos/sky,mp4" type="video/mp4">
          Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
    </video>

    <video id="leftHalf" width="100%" height="100%" preload autoplay loop muted>
          <source src="videos/MVI_2987_1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
          <source src="videos/MVI_2987_1.webmhd.webm" type="video/webm">
           Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
    </video>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ok, so what's wrong with what you have?

Comment: what's the matter with the output? what does it do that it shouldn't be doing? can you upload a demo or screen?

Comment: I changed it so you can test yourself. They come up side by side, but they aren't the full height of the browser window

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if I understood it well, but you want the videos to be like full size of the page? something like this?

**[Online Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2sxeu1om/)**

If it is, change the iframe parameters to 100% like this

```
<iframe id="leftHalf" width="100%" height="100%" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k">
</iframe>

<iframe id="rightHalf" width="100%" height="100%" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k">
</iframe>
```

------------- **Update Edit** -------------

For html video element:

**[Online Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2sxeu1om/1/)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="leftHalf">
    <video preload autoplay loop muted>
        <source src="examples/video-example.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="examples/video-example.webm" type="video/webm" />
        Video not supported.
    </video>
</div>


<div class="rightHalf">
    <video preload autoplay loop muted>
        <source src="examples/video-example.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="examples/video-example.webm" type="video/webm" />
        Video not supported.
    </video>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.leftHalf {
    position:absolute;
    left: 0px;
    height:100%;
    width:50%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.rightHalf {
    position:absolute;
    right: 0px;
    height:100%;
    width:50%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.leftHalf video {
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
.rightHalf video {
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This solution works with iframes, but not with the html <video> element. I can re-edit the code again.