# How to stop iframe video jumping in Chrome columns

Tags: html, css, iframe

so I'm trying to display two videos beside each other with a title above them. I used the column attribute and it works fine visually, however, whenever I hit play on any video in the second column it magically jumps down to the first column in the next row and loses all pause/play capability... This is a problem that only happens in chrome, IE and firefox seem to play it fine..

Additionally, if anyone has any other way of displaying it that would be great. I tried making each title and video in it's own div, then displaying those divs as inline, but for some reason that didn't work; it still showed them one on top of the other.

Here's my code:

```
<div class="topfloor" align="center">
    <h3>Living Room and Den</h3>
        <p>
            <iframe width="480" height="360"       src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/jLijkSO7aGM?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </p>


    <h3>Upstairs Bedroom</h3>
        <p>
            <iframe width="480" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/4SG5JVIKWRk?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </p>
</div>
```

and:

```
   .topfloor{
        background-color: rgba(70,130,180, 0.9);
        padding-top: 10px;
        -webkit-column-count: 2;
        -moz-column-count: 2;
        column-count: 2;
        }

.topfloor h3{
        margin-top: 0px;
        color: rgb(0,0,0);
        background-color: rgba(70,130,180, 0.9);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already answered a similar question like **[this before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26007115/two-full-screen-videos-background-side-by-side-in-one-window)**.
Here's the trick and it will also make your videos responsive for smaller screens

Your HTML goes like this:

```
<div id="leftHalf">
    <h3>Living Room and Den</h3>
        <iframe  width="100%" height="100%" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/IJNR2EpS0jw"></iframe>
</div>

<div id="rightHalf">
    <h3>Living Room and Den</h3>
        <iframe  width="100%" height="100%" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/IJNR2EpS0jw"></iframe>
</div>
```

and your CSS:

```
#leftHalf {
    width: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#rightHalf {
    width: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**Check out the [online example here](http://jsfiddle.net/qqy1k0cp/)**

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.. This doesn't actually solve my issue though, as I don't want the video's to take up half the screen. I just wanted the regular 480x360 videos side by side, with the headers above. I was using columns, which worked fine visually. But in chrome if I hit play on any video in the second column it would jump to a different position... this was not a problem with other browsers

Comment: Then just exchange the width and height values for the iframes with `480x360` , or wrap the 2 divs inside of a main wrapper so they'll be responsive for that main wrapper. This is the best way of displaying 2 videos side by side and make them responsive so you don't have problems in smaller screens later, but you can always change and play with the values to style them for your needs. Although you need to notice that their width and height will always maintain the same `480x360` http://jsfiddle.net/qqy1k0cp/1/ and of course they're occupying half of the screen because they have no wrapper